# Validate user in Azure Active Directory; Not using SSO but using username and password

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

With the recent release of Azure AD, we would like to use Azure AD for our web application authentication, but we do not want to use SSO. We do not want users to be redirected to the Microsoft Account login screen, and then come back. We want to supply them with the login credential screen where we capture their username and password, and then we want to programatically do the authentication against Azure AD, and get back the claims identity.

The problem I have is that I cannot see how I can do that using the Graph API, and all the examples that look like it might work, only works on the previous [0.8] release. There is such a mix of examples that is supposed to work, but they don't simply because of the new release.

Can anyone tell me if this is even possible, and maybe point me in the direction of how to do it please.

I do not want to use ACS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is not technically possible with Azure Active Directory today.  That scenario could possibly be supported in the future, so check back from time to time.

We really encourage developers to rely on the in browser sign in experience.  The reason is that because the browser allows the server to define the experience, it allows for much greater flexibility with respect to the kinds of credentials that can be employed.  For instance, if you code your app to use only username and password, then it may need to be updated in order to take advantage of two factor authentication.  If you rely on the browser based experience then your app can be totally agnostic to whether 2FA is being employed, or any other kind of authentication dance.

We recognize that there are some scenarios where this is not ideal or even practical and are looking at solutions to those scenarios that may be supported in the future.

Comment: Thanks Rich, but I do not understand what could be so hard to have your API direct what we do. For example, if you have an API that expects, (and supports), 2FA or whatever future goodies there might be, and developers use your API, what is the problem? I would appreciate any future updates. At the moment we cannot use Azure AD, because of this shortcoming, so we had to revert back to standard web credentials.

Comment: To add a bit more detail, Different credential types may require different credential collection requirements.  If a one time password is used there may need to be a an extra edit box added to collect the one time password.  There are other examples of UI differences between credential types.  If cred UI is baked in to an application then the whole app may be required to be updated to change the credential collection UI when a new credential type is supported.  If the UI is delivered from the server, then the App can remain blissfully ignorant of the credentials that the user presented.