# Authenticate a web application user on Azure Active Directory using OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, nancy, azure-active-directory

### Context

I'm building a web application deployed to Azure Webapps where users need to sign in. To accomplish this, I'm leveraging Azure AD with [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1). Since I'm using Nancy (with the ASP.NET host) instead of MVC, I can't follow the official Azure AD MVC examples where all the OAuth handling seems to happen magically in the background.

Redirecting to the OAuth endpoint is straight-forward, and the user is also correctly redirected back to my application with an authorization code.

### Problem

Now I need retrieve the user ID in order to match it to the user database in my application. I'm using ADAL for this, because this is basically step [D & E of the authorization code grant flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1), from what I understand.

Now what puzzles me is that this use case is not supported by Azure AD, stating that

> The client '[ClientId]' and resource '[ResouceId]' identify the same application.

Also, as indicated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29705724/219187), *"ADAL is not meant to achieve web sign-on in a web application."*

I've been able to work around this problem by creating two applications in Azure AD, as suggested by [this blog](http://blaug.azurewebsites.net/aad-security-with-nancyfx-part1/), but it feels like I misunderstood something. This could very well be the case, as I am new to OAuth and Azure AD.

**So my question is, what is the correct way to authenticate a user from a non-MVC web application using Azure AD?**

Answer (score 1):

the OWIN middleware should work with non-ASP.NET as well. See for example http://unlustrously55.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=24287735&item=13 - in your case you will have to use the OpenId Connect one or the ww-federation one.

Comment: I'm using the ASP.NET hosting of Nancy, because I run the application as Azure Webapp. I clarified this in the question. The link you provided does apparently only apply to self-hosted Nancy.

Comment: I am not a Nancy expert - hence I cannot tell whether that can be generalized to the ASP.NET hosting of Nancy. However it look like the OWIN middleware pipeline should be hostable in that scenario too - the contrary would kind of go against the very raison d'etre of OWIN. Let me notify folks of this thread, let's see if they have suggestions

Comment: You should also be able to use the OWIN middleware with Nancy on IIS. Add the Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb package to your WebApp. Then follow the above linked instructions. You don't need the Main method anymore, but most of the stuff after that should be the same (Startup class, Configuration method, etc.).  You may also skip the line ".UseNancy()" if you have Nancy configured directly in Web.Config.

Comment: @Tratcher I didn't get notified of your comment, so I'm only seeing it now. I'll take a look at that approach, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this purely for users inside your organisation/tenant? It sounds like it.

Why don't you use an App Registration in Azure AD and grant it permissions to access the users profile? You should then be able to retrieve a user's UPN from the token.  Please see here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service